# Animation and shading

Tags: animation, shaders

Can any one make or reffer to a video tutorial wich can give the same result of the animation of the flag featured in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vDjlrlA0IM at 0:13 ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hi. [Requests for tutorials are considered off topic here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1). If it requires a full tutorial the question is either [too broad and needs to be narrowed down](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62) to a more specific issue; or it can be solved with a simple web search, which you can easily do yourself. Please don't post another question. If you could you rephrase the current one to read more like a direct inquiry about your issue, rather than pointing you to a link, you can [edit] it so it can be reopened.

Comment: The video is a laundry liquid TV commercial. Which flag do you mean at 0:13? To me, it's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: @Blunder I think he's talking about the flag that is rolling down on the top right of the screen with the Unilever log

Comment: @user154959 Please edit your question and show an animated gif of the flag so that question is made more clear